# Is the monotone convergence theorem bidirectional?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Say I have $(f_n)$ with $f_1 \le f_2 \le ...$ and I know that $\lim_n\int f_n<\infty$ exists, does that imply $f_n$ converges a.e.?

Most formulations I have seen of the monotone convergence theorem assume that $f_n$ converges, and continue to show that the integral limit exists. I'm wondering if the theorem can also be used in the other direction?

Answer (score 1):

Assume in addition that $f_1$ is integrable. The limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ exists for each $x$ in the extended sense, so in this sense $f(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ is well-defined. One can show now that $f$ is measurable, and since $f$ is bounded from below by an integrable function (namely $f_1$), it is quasi-integrable (which means that the integrable exists in the extended sense and can be infinite in the worst case). Moreover one can show $\int f=\lim \int f_n$, and by assumption, the right hand side is even finite. So, $f$ is integrable, and this implies that $f$ has to be finite almost everywhere. For details, see
[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem).

Comment: Ah right, in the extended reals all monotone sequences converge. So weird :)
When you say "one can show $\int f = \lim_n\int f_n$" I assume you mean by mct?

Comment: I know the mct as you formulated it above, so that whole thing is the mct for me. For proofs follow the link I have given above.
If you dont like the extended reals, then remember that a monotone sequence is either bounded or not. If it is bounded, then it is convergent, and if not, then it goes to intinity. In either case the limit makes sense. :)